# Binding dataset to listbox showing just 1 record

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, listbox

I have WPF project based on MVVM.  In my view I have the next ListBox

```
<ListBox BorderBrush="#6797c8" BorderThickness="2" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=CategoriesDS}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="MainCategories/Category"/>
```

And this is my code at ViewModel:

```
private DataSet categoriesDS;

public DataSet CategoriesDS
{
    get
    {
        if (categoriesDS == null)
        {
            categoriesDS = _dal.GetCategoriesTables();
        }
        return categoriesDS;
    }
    set
    {
        categoriesDS = value;
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this,
                  new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CategoriesDS"));
        }
    }
}
```

My DataSet contains 2 tables and the first table ("MainCategories") contains 3 rows.
When I run my app I'm seeing just the first row of "MainCategories" table.

Why is the ListBox showing just 1 row? I want to show the entire table.

Thanks

Comment: Try returning a Table.  Not a DataSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to bind to the table directly. You can create another property that just accesses the `CategoriesDS` property and then bind against the new property:

```
public DataView MainCategories 
{ 
  get { return CategoriesDS.MainCategories.DefaultView; } 
}
```

or

```
public DataView MainCategories 
{ 
  get { return CategoriesDS.Tables[0].DefaultView; } 
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ListBox BorderBrush="#6797c8" BorderThickness="2" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=MainCategories}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Category"/>
```